# Private pods with implementation details hidden in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I wish to create a pod based library which will have implementation of functions hidden. I have searched around and a bit and have found that usually all implementation is visible in the project where I use this pod.

Is there anyhow I can make it work like a framework?

Comment: hidden functions mean it will be access by your other pod? but not the app?

Comment: @Ankit have a look this [blog](http://www.yudiz.com/creating-your-own-ios-framework-and-distributed-using-cocoapods/)